# What is a good JS/Regex Positive Lookbehind Alternative in Safari for splitting text including hyphens?

Tags: javascript, regex, safari, regex-lookarounds

I've read through a [great article](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/fit-text-to-circle) how to position and scale text in SVG-Circles. The text-wrapping algorithm shown there is using following line of code:

```js
const words = text.split(/\s+/g); // To hyphenate: /\s+|(?<=-)/
```

The idea of this snippet is to create a list out of a word "Self-Sizing Text in a Circle" -> ["Self-Sizing", "Text", "in", "a", "Circle"].

^^The algorithm is working like a charm, but the hyphenate-version is not working in Safari:

```js
const words = text.split(/\s+|(?<=-)/g); // Not working in Safari
```

> Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name

The outcome should be ["Self-", "Sizing", "Text", "in", "a", "Circle"]. Notice the split of "Self-Sizing" keeping the hyphen as part of word one.

To get the example running in all browsers I bring up this solution:

```js
text = text.replace(/-/g, "- "); // add a space next to the hyphen
const words = text.split(/\s+/g); // split using spaces
```

However solving this in a regex exclusive way seems to be most elegant especially when widening the scope of characters to be used for wrapping.

Therefore I'd like to ask you as a community whether you have a better idea.

A full playground can be found [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/9c54e47e8d544938bc40a0bb999b4a04?version=3.44.3) (helpers.js -> line 7) or you can have a look into the Stack Snipped below:

```js
const text = "Self-Sizing Text in a Circle";
const words = text.split(/\s+|(?<=-)/g);
console.log(words);
```

Comment: I think you should add some more background to your question about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `const words = text.match(/[^\s-]+-*/g)` might be all you need if you just want to extract non-whitespace chunks that have no `-` inside but can have `-` at the end.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Oh that is just really cool.

Comment: Maybe `const words = text.match(/[^\s-]+-?|-/g)` is more precise in this case. It will match any one or more chars other than whitespace and `-` and then a single optional `-`, or a `-` char.

Comment: Leon, please clarify what you want to do with a sting like `-A--B--`?

Comment: I don't have the need to handle such an edge case in my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.split(/\s+|(?<=-)/)` operation means the string is split into chunks of non-whitespace chars and at the locations right after a `-` char. It means you can *extract* any chunks of chars other than whitespace with an optional hyphen right after, or any other hyphen (that will actually be the hyphen(s) right after the first alternative).

```js
const words = text.match(/[^\s-]+-?|-/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Qcm5b/1). *Details*:

- `[^\s-]+-?` - one or more chars other than whitespace and `-` and then an optional hyphen
- `|` - or
- `-` - a hyphen.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "Self-Sizing Text in a Circle";
const words = text.match(/[^\s-]+-?|-/g)
console.log(words);
```

Note that if you do not need to care for consecutive, leading and trailing hyphens, you can simply use

```js
const words = text.match(/[^\s-]+-?/g)
```

`[^\s-]+-?` will match one or more chars other than whitespace and `-` and then a single optional `-`.